# What is the correct approach to solve SPOJ BALNUM?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I am trying to solve [BALNUM](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BALNUM/) problem on SPOJ. However I am unable to find approach to solve it. I am understanding that this is a dynamic programming problem but I am not able to find the recurrence function since number of occurrence of all digits(0-9) matter here.

Can someone please give me a hint. Whole algorithm or code is not required. Just a hint as how can I find the recurrence function for it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you calculate the ammount of balanced numbers of given length?

Try to think about it that way - knowing how many balanced numbers have length 0, 1, 2, ... n how can you calculate how many balanced numbers have length n+1

Comment: I have been thinking that way but problem is I guess length is not enough to know how many balanced numbers for n+1 length. State or something of every digit also has to be known. Can you please edit your answer with the suggested recurrence function?